# How Do I add Rel No Follow to this PHP Coding?

Tags: php

How do I insert the no follow code into this PHP Coding?

```
<?php 
$url_show = trim_string($url);
echo("<a href=http://www." . $url . " target=_blank'><h2>" .  $url_show . "<h2></a>"); 
?>
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: `<a rel="nofollow" ...`

Comment: looking for this? `echo "<a rel='nofollow' href=http://www." . $url . " target=_blank'><h2>" .  $url_show . "<h2></a>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `rel='nofollow'` as:

```
echo("
<a rel='nofollow' href=http://www." . $url . " target=_blank'>
<h2>" . $url_show . "
</h2>
</a>");
```

Also use ending tag for `</h2>`

Comment: @Matte: dont forget to mark as accepted, it will help to others. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work